# Visual Studio builds release that cannot be run: Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file

Tags: windows, visual-studio, security

I just updated Visual Studio, created a new project (C# .Net Forms). I can run the project in debug, but if I try to run the release it says:

"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."

My account has admin privilege. I tried "Run as admin" but that also fails. If I try to change the security on the folder that also fails.

There is no other exe on my system that gives me this problem.

Comment: I have Windows Defender, which I tried to stop from TaskMgr but couldn't

Comment: Add the project folder as an exception / exclusion in Windows Defender

Answer (score 0):

Dave S (comments above) has a working solution, instructions at:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26